# Labels not converting properly from SHP to KML

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, labeling, convert, kml

Since the last ArcGIS Pro Update (running 3.2.1), when I convert an SHP to KML, the labels are not populating correctly. I have everything set up correctly with the pop ups, the title, and the labels. It keeps defaulting to the same field no matter the type. I have added a new field with the label that I want and tried it as a float, number, text, and double and it still goes to the other field. These are point files and I have done this conversion before several times without this issue.

Comment: It the source data [Shapefile] in a different projection other than WGS84?

Comment: Yes, it is in WGS1984.

Comment: I figured it out. I used to be able to get the labels to appear just by adjusting the labels in GIS but the display field under layer properties is what I needed to change.

Comment: You can answer your own question, glad you figured it out.